# VM remote decryption

Tags: encryption, virtual-machine

I’m looking to offer potential customers a free trial of a product by way of offering a VM for download.

However we could like to control the licensing/trial by remote disk encryption/decryption.

Basically I'm looking for a way to get an full disk encrypted VM to make a call to remote host and check if the license is still valid and then pass it a decryption key.

So question is, has anyone heard/seen/done this? Is it possible?

Thanks in advance for any response.

red_brick

Answer (score 0):

Consider the Risk associated:

1. Users download the trial VM.
2. You decrypt within trial period.
3. **Some** Users will copy the files and won't buy the product.